# Dúvida em como publicar ou não um método num web service, esconder

Tags: c#, web-service, rest, wcf

O que vou perguntar não sei se é possível e nem como fazer. Bem, tenho um REST que até agora está ok. Aí, alteraram uma regra aqui que afeta diretamente a API REST. Eu tenho um método que gera ID para parceiros. Até então está bom, mas agora preciso continuar gerando os ID's, mas da seguinte forma. Se atender determinada regra aqui, o ID é gerado apenas para o nosso suporte. Eles interferem no PDV e tentam resolver. Caso o acesso remoto que eles fazem, não conseguir atender, aí eles usam o parceiro que será consumido via API REST. Existe alguma forma de eu criar um método que possa ser visível apenas para uma determinada aplicação e etc, ou não tem como fazer isso?

Como falei uso REST com WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Uma ideia que pode ser interessante é você separar seus serviços por cliente. Assim cada cliente tem referência para o seu serviço e aos métodos que ele deseja executar em específico, exemplo:

Cliente A acessa os métodos do ServicoA:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="")]
public interface IServicoA
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="/ObterId")]
    MetodoGeraId()
}
```

Cliente B acessa os métodos do ServicoB:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="")]
public interface IServicoB
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="/ObterAlgo")]
    MetodoB();
}
```

Outra opção seria você customizar como o serviço WCF para autenticar e autorizar o cliente, analisando as suas credenciais, verificando se essas são válidas em um determinado repositório e determinar se ele tem ou não direito para executar a operação/método do seu serviço.

Então, ao chamar um método do seu serviço, o usuário passaria as credenciais (usuário/senha) para você validar no seu serviço WCF se ele pode ou não executar aquele método.